# Pass multiple checkbox values to PHP Mail

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm trying to pass checkbox values to PHP but the interests field shows up blank. I need to display all the interests values checked. And send out an email. I've included all three parts. All the other fields are displaying properly.

Here's the HTML part

```
                            <form id="register-form" class="register-form register" action="php/register.php" method="post">
                                
                    
                                <input class="register-input name-input white-input" required="" name="register_names" placeholder="Full Name*" type="text">
                                
                                <input class="register-input name-email white-input" required="" name="register_phone" placeholder="Phone*" type="text">
                            
                                <input class="register-input name-email white-input" required="" name="register_email" placeholder="Email Adress*" type="email">
                                
                                <input class="register-input name-email white-input"  name="register_company" placeholder="Company" type="text">
                                
                                <table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input class="register-input name-email white-input" name="register_city" placeholder="City" type="text"></td>
                                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><input class="register-input name-email white-input" name="register_zip" placeholder="Zip" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                
                                <table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="8">
                                    
                                    <tr><fieldset>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Practice" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Practice<br />
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Training" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Training<br />
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Workout" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Workout<br />
                                            
                                        </td>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </tr>
                                    
                                </table>
                               
                                <input value="Submit Request" class="register-submit" type="submit">
                                    
                            </form>
```

Here's the JQuery part for validation

```
    $('#register-form').each( function(){
        var form = $(this);
        //form.validate();
        form.submit(function(e) {
            if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                jQuery.post(this.action,{
                    'names':$('input[name="register_names"]').val(),
                    'email':$('input[name="register_email"]').val(),
                    'phone':$('input[name="register_phone"]').val(),
                    'company':$('input[name="register_company"]').val(),
                    'city':$('input[name="register_city"]').val(),
                    'zip':$('input[name="register_zip"]').val(),
                    'interests':$('checkbox[name="interests"]').val(),
                },function(data){
                    form.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(this).siblings('p.register_success_box').show();
                    });
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    })
```

Lastly, here's the PHP part to generate the email

```
<?php

$field_first_name = $_POST['names'];

$field_email = $_POST['email'];

$field_phone = $_POST['phone'];

$field_company = $_POST['company'];

$field_city = $_POST['city'];

$field_zip = $_POST['zip'];

$interests = (is_array($_POST['interests']) ? $_POST['interests'] : []);
$interests = (count($interests) > 0 ? implode(',', $interests) : 'none');


$mail_to = 'to@email.com';

$subject = 'Message from a landing page visitor '.$field_first_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_first_name."\n";

$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";

$body_message .= 'Company: '.$field_company."\n";

$body_message .= 'City: '.$field_city."\n";

$body_message .= 'Zip: '.$field_zip."\n";

$body_message .= 'Interests:  '.trim($interests).' ';


$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


----------


        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `$('checkbox[name="interests"]').val()` give you when you run it in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing it shows blank. "Interests:"

Comment: Sorry. It reads as "Interests: none"

Comment: I doubt that since that is what your email should look like. I ask again: What does the jQuery selector return to you when you run it in the browser console?

Comment: `$('checkbox[name="interests"]').val()` will only return the first checkbox matching the selector - the .val() documentation page explains this. And in any case it won't match any of your checkboxes because their name is `interests[]`, not `interests`. You're massively overcomplicating this whole thing, though - you can just use jQuery's `.serialize()` function to automatically serialize all the form fields with one line of code, instead of trying to pick out each individual field with separate code. That'll save you time, simplify your code, and solve your problem.

Comment: P.s. `It reads as "Interests: none"`...No, that's what the`$interests` variable in php will contain (and put into the email) after it's realised there were no matching $_POST variables and used it's default value. But that's not what you were asked about - you were asked what the jQuery code `$('checkbox[name="interests"]').val()` returns. As I've just explained, that won't return anything. Remember that you can debug your code step by step...you don't have to purely rely on what the end result looks like - otherwise no-one would ever be able to solve problems occurring within their code

Comment: I removed `$('checkbox[name="interests"]').val()` from the validation code because it not really needed. I had it in there originally to see if a value was selected. Thanks for insight and help.

Comment: We're not talking about any validation code though, we're talking about its usage in the jQuery.post options

Comment: Can you give me a example because I've tried several things and still can't get it to work.

Comment: Example of what exactly? What have you already tried? If you consult the documentation of jQuery serialize() there are already examples of usage. If you're stuck, update the question with what you tried and what the issue was

Comment: To be clear, you don't have a PHP Mailer problem yet, you only have a jQuery/AJAX/form problem, right? Work on that, get it over HTTP to PHP, ignore email for now completely, just log and/or dump. Also, while you debug this, your fade stuff is probably going to cause more problems, you might want to disable that for now.

Answer (score -1):

I found the error in the php code below:

```
$interests = (is_array($_POST['interests']) ? $_POST['interests'] : []);

$interests = (count($interests) > 0 ? implode(',', $interests) : 'none');
```

If you get any checkbox value it did not directly come with an array format, so that's why this condition is not correct.

You have to do something like this:

```
$interests = $_POST['interests']!='' ? $_POST['interests'] : '');

$interests = ($interests!='' ? implode(',', $interests) : 'none');
```

Comment: It seems maybe.you didn't read any of the comments before posting? And the answer doesn't really make any sense anyway, even if those comments weren't there. An empty string would never be posted, presuming the data is serialized correctly on the client side (which, if you read the comments, is actually where the real problem exists in the OP's code).

Comment: @Henry thanks for the example even though it didn't work. I appreciate the explanation.